# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED with socket.io on Node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have a basic client-server setup with Node.js:

**Server**

```
var port = 8000;
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(port);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/site'));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/site/index.html');
});

server.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Listening on port " + port + "...");
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log("A user connected");
});
```

**Client**

```
var socket = io.connect("http://72.53.66.228:8000");

socket.on('connect', function() {
    console.log("Connected.");
});
```

However, I keep getting this error in my browser's console, and I'm not sure why:

```
GET http://72.53.66.228:8000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1419738402131-5 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I should also note that I'm running an Apache webserver and I'm using the ProxyPass directive to let Node.js serve off [a subdirectory](http://evades.me/CAH/)

Comment: try `io.connect("http://72.53.66.228/CAH");`

Comment: @generalhenry I tried that before, exact same error from the browser. I updated it so you can see for yourself.

Comment: `io.connect({path:'/CAH/socket.io'})` kinda sorta works

Comment: @generalhenry Thanks, I am getting several "A user connected" logs on my server console. Now I'm getting different 500 and 402 errors - I'm not sure if that's normal, but at least I'm getting a valid connection now.

Comment: check the apache logs, add some logging to your node server, the web sockets breaking is expected, but the polling should be working

Comment: @generalhenry Your comment on the path actually was the solution to the issues I was having - if you'd like to post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue was the path.  Since Apache was only proxying the /CAH/. . . path.

The trouble with `io.connect("http://72.53.66.228/CAH");` was that socket.io does a 'cleaver' trick where it interpreted /CAH as the room rather than as the path.

The solution is to set the path option thusly: `io.connect({path:'/CAH/socket.io'})` which causes the socket.io client to connect to the correct urls.